# Run a specifiable number of commands in parallel - contrasting xargs -P, GNU parallel, and "moreutils" parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, xargs, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to run multiple mongodump's on 26 servers in a bash script.

I can run 3 commands like

`mongodump -h staging .... &
 mongodump -h production .... &
 mongodump -h web ... &`

at the same time, and when one finishes I want to start another mongodump.

I can't run all 26 mongodumps commands at the same time, the server will run out on CPU. Max 3 mongodumps at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried replacing every third `&`  with a `;` ?

Answer (score 13):

You can use **`xarg`'s `-P` option** to **run a specifiable number of invocations in parallel**:

<sup>Note that the `-P` option is [not mandated by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html), but both GNU `xargs` and BSD/macOS `xargs` support it.</sup>

```
xargs -P 3 -n 1 mongodump -h <<<'staging production web more stuff and so on'
```

This runs `mongodump -h staging`,  `mongodump -h production`, and  `mongodump -h web` in parallel, waits for all 3 calls to finish, then continues with `mongodump -h more`,  `mongodump -h stuff`, and  `mongodump -h and`, and so on.

`-n 1` grabs a *single* argument from the input stream and calls `mongodump`; adjust as needed, single- or double-quoting arguments in the input if necessary.

Note: *GNU* `xargs` - but not BSD `xargs` - supports `-P 0`, where `0` means: "run as many processes as possible simultaneously."

By default, the arguments supplied via stdin are *appended* to the specified command.
If you need to control *where* the respective arguments are placed in the resulting commands,

- provide the arguments *line by line*
- use `-I {}` to indicate that, and to define `{}` as the placeholder for each input line.

```
xargs -P 3 -I {} mongodump -h {} after <<<$'staging\nproduction\nweb\nmore\nstuff'
```

Now each input arguments is substituted for `{}`, allowing argument `after` to come after.

Note, however, that each input line is invariably passed as a *single* argument.

<sup>BSD/macOS `xargs` would allow you to combine `-n` with `-J {}`, without needing to provide line-based input, but GNU `xargs` doesn't support `-J`.

In short: only BSD/macOS allows you to combine placement of the input arguments with reading *multiple* arguments at once.</sup>

Note that `xargs` does *not* serialize stdout output from commands in parallel, so that **output from parallel processes can arrive *interleaved***.
**Use *GNU* `parallel` to avoid this problem** - see below.

---

#### Alternative: `parallel`

`xargs` has the advantage of being a standard utility, so on platforms where it supports `-P`, there are no prerequisites.

In the Linux world (though also on macOS via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)) there are two purpose-built utilities for running commands in parallel, which, unfortunately, share the same name; **typically, you must install them on demand**:

- `parallel` (a binary) from the `moreutils` package - see [its home page](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/).
- The - much more powerful - GNU `parallel` (a Perl script) from the `parallel` package <sup>Thanks, [twalberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253222/twalberg).</sup> - see [its home page](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

If you already have a `parallel` utility, `parallel --version` will tell you which one it is (GNU `parallel` reports a version number and copyright information, "moreutils" `parallel` complains about an invalid option and shows a syntax summary).

#### Using the "moreutils" `parallel`:

```
parallel -j 3 -n 1 mongodump -h -- staging production web more stuff and so on

# Using -i to control placement of the argument, via {}
# Only *1* argument at at time supported in that case.
parallel -j 3 -i mongodump -h {} after -- staging production web more stuff and so on
```

Unlike `xargs`, this `parallel` implementation doesn't take the arguments to pass through from *stdin*; all pass-through arguments must be passed on the command line, following `--`.

From what I can tell, the only features this `parallel` implementation offers beyond what `xargs` can do is:

- The `-l` option allows delaying further invocations until the system load overage is below the specified threshold.
- Possibly this (from the `man` page): "stdout and stderr is serialised through a corresponding internal pipe, in order to prevent annoying concurrent output behaviour.", though I've found this *not* be the case in the version whose `man` page is dated 2009-07-2 - see last section.

#### Using GNU `parallel`:

<sup>Tip of the hat to [Ole Tange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363028/ole-tange) for his help.</sup>

```
parallel -P 3 -n 1 mongodump -h <<<$'staging\nproduction\nweb\nmore\nstuff\nand\nso\non'

# Alternative, using ::: followed by the target-command arguments.
parallel -P 3 -n 1 mongodump -h ::: staging production web more stuff and so on 

# Using -n 1 and {} to control placement of the argument.
# Note that using -N rather than -n would allow per-argument placement control
# with {1}, {2}, ...
parallel -P 3 -n 1 mongodump -h {} after <<<$'staging\nproduction\nweb\nmore\nstuff\nand'
```

- As with `xargs`, pass-through arguments are supplied via *stdin*, but GNU `parallel` also supports placing them on the command line, after a configurable separator (`:::` by default).
- Unlike with `xargs`, each input *line* is considered a single argument.
- *Caveat*: If your command involves *quoted strings*, you must use `-q` to pass them through as distinct arguments; e.g., `parallel -q sh -c 'echo hi, $0' ::: there` only works with `-q`.
- As with *GNU* `xargs`, you can use `-P 0` to run as many invocations *as possible* at once, taking full advantage of the machine's capabilities, meaning, according to Ole, "until GNU Parallel hits a limit (file handles and processes)".

  - Conveniently, *omitting* `-P` doesn't just run *one* process at a time, as the other utilities do, but runs one process *per CPU core*.
- Output from commands being executed in parallel is by default automatically *serialized* (grouped) on per-process basis, to avoid interleaved output.

  - This is generally desirable, but note that it means that you'll only start to see the *other* commands' output once the first one that has created output has *terminated*.
  - Use option `--line-buffer` (`--lb` in more recent versions) to opt out of this behavior or
    `-u` (`--ungroup`) to allow even a single output line to mix output from different processes; see the manual for details.

GNU `parallel`, which is designed to be a better successor to `xargs`, offers many more features: a notable example is the ability to [perform sophisticated transformations on the pass-through arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Replacement-strings), optionally based on Perl *regular expressions*; see also: `man parallel` and `man parallel_tutorial`.

---

#### Optional reading: testing output serialization behavior

The following commands test how `xargs` and the two `parallel` implements deal with interleaved output from commands being run in parallel - whether they show output as it arrives, or try to serialize it:

There are **2 levels of serialization**, both of which introduce overhead:

- Line-level serialization: Prevent *partial* lines from different processes to be mixed on a *single* output line.
- Process-level serialization: Ensure that all output lines from a given process are grouped together.
  This is the most user-friendly method, but note that it means that you'll only start to see the *other* commands' output (in sequence) once the first one that has created output has *terminated*.

**From what I can tell, only GNU `parallel` offers *any* serialization** (despite what the "moreutils" `parallel` man page dated 2009-07-2 says<sup>[1]</sup>
), and it **supports *both* methods.**

The commands below assume the existence of executable script `./tst` with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf "$$: [1/2] entering with arg(s): $*"
sleep $(( $RANDOM / 16384 ))
printf " $$: [2/2] finished entering\n"
echo "  $$: stderr line" >&2
echo "$$: stdout line"
sleep $(( $RANDOM / 8192 ))
echo "    $$: exiting"
```

---

**`xargs`** (both the GNU and BSD/macOS implementations, as found on Ubuntu 16.04 and macOS 10.12):

No serialization happens: a single output line can contain output from multiple processes.

```
$ xargs -P 3 -n 1 ./tst <<<'one two three'
2593: [1/2] entering with arg(s): one2594: [1/2] entering with arg(s): two 2593: [2/2] finished entering
  2593: stderr line
2593: stdout line
2596: [1/2] entering with arg(s): three   2593: exiting
 2594: [2/2] finished entering
  2594: stderr line
2594: stdout line
 2596: [2/2] finished entering
  2596: stderr line
2596: stdout line
   2594: exiting
   2596: exiting
```

---

**"moreutils" `parallel`** (version whose `man` page is dated 2009-07-02)

No serialization happens: a single output line can contain output from multiple processes.

```
$ parallel -j 3 ./tst -- one two three
3940: [1/2] entering with arg(s): one3941: [1/2] entering with arg(s): two3942: [1/2] entering with arg(s): three 3941: [2/2] finished entering
  3941: stderr line
3941: stdout line
 3942: [2/2] finished entering
  3942: stderr line
3942: stdout line
 3940: [2/2] finished entering
  3940: stderr line
3940: stdout line
   3941: exiting
   3942: exiting
```

---

**GNU `parallel`** (version 20170122)

Process-level serialization (grouping) happens by default.
Use `--line-buffer` (`--lb` in newer versions) to choose line-level serialization instead, or opt out of any kind of serialization with `-u`
(`--ungroup`).

Note how, in each group, stderr output comes *after* stdout output (whereas the man page that comes with version 20170122 claims that stderr output comes *first*).

```
$ parallel -P 3 ./tst ::: one two three
2544: [1/2] entering with arg(s): one 2544: [2/2] finished entering
2544: stdout line
   2544: exiting
  2544: stderr line
2549: [1/2] entering with arg(s): three 2549: [2/2] finished entering
2549: stdout line
   2549: exiting
  2549: stderr line
2546: [1/2] entering with arg(s): two 2546: [2/2] finished entering
2546: stdout line
   2546: exiting
  2546: stderr line
```

---

<sup>[1] "stdout and stderr is serialised through a corresponding internal pipe, in order to prevent annoying concurrent output behaviour."

Do tell me if I'm missing something.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you just exclude every 3rd `&` (or use a `;` if it's all on one line) then it will not execute the whole thing in parallel.

Eg:

```
echo "Hello" & sleep 1 ;
echo "Hello Again" & sleep 1 ;
echo "Once More" & sleep 1 ;
```

Comment: For long-running background processes you need to use `wait` to ensure that they've finished.