# Using Linux bash scripting to run multiple jobs simultaneously on HPCC

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I want to run 20 jobs simultaneously on HPCC using a bash script. I wrote the code below, but this code cannot run the jobs simultaneously. Can everyone help me out with how can I modify this code to do that?

```
cd $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR

for((i=0;i<20;i++))
do
    cd $i
    #running a code
    cd ../
    
done
```

~
~

Comment: `xargs` or GNU `parallel` if you have access to those.  Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651475/run-a-specifiable-number-of-commands-in-parallel-contrasting-xargs-p-gnu-par

Comment: I see SLURM somewhere... what about a job array?

Comment: BTW, why is this tagged `python`???

Comment: Thanks, by job array, do you mean something like below? 
/home/.....
@Poshi

Answer (score 0):

Put jobs to background and wait for completion?

```bash
declare -a pids

for ((i=0;i<20;i++))
do
    (
        cd $i
        #running a code
    ) &
    pids+=($!)
done

wait ${pids[*]}
```